# How to pass a value from a recursive method to the method which called it?

Tags: java, recursion

I am calling a recursive method(let's say method b) from a method(let's say method a) . Now , after method b is finished computing the result , i want it to return the value back to method a. How should i proceed?

I tried calling the method a inside of method b , but couldn't do so as it would disrupt the flow of method b.

```
public long supercheck(long ognums) {
    if (ognums < 10) {
        return ognums;
    } else
        return sums(ognums);
}

public long sums(long ognums) {
    if (ognums == 0)
        return 0;
    return ognums % 10 + sums(ognums / 10);
}
```

Here, I want to pass the return value of sums method to supercheck method .

Comment: you are already passing return value of sums() to supercheck()

Comment: Why can't you just replace `return sums(ognums)` with `long s = sums(ognums)`? Then you have the result in `s`.

Comment: Initially i'm passing a value to supercheck from where it is passing it to sums for computing the sum of digits . Now i again want to pass this to supercheck until the sum of digits is less than 10

Comment: or  this:  while (ognums < 10) ognums=sums(ognums); return ognums;

Comment: Oh! I get it... I'll try this out. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: don't know - it was just a question if I understood you correvtly.